# Where can I ask a question about harmfulness/benefits/control of an indoor insect pest?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

Is there an appropriate place to ask a question about harmfulness/benefits/control of an indoor insect pest? I keep looking at [Gardening and Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) but it's outdoors. Is it appropriate on [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) (which seems more geared towards science)?

Comment: Questions about bugs are on-topic on SO... good luck!

Comment: I was thinking maybe [DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but I doubt that will fly...

Comment: @rene http://cdn.iwastesomuchtime.com/January-10-2012-17-43-29-ScreenShot20120109at3.31.12PM.jpg

Comment: You could try [lifehacks](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/).  They're all about manipulating real-world bugs.

Comment: @Zibbobz [I flatly refuse to post a question on Lifehacks.](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=3439396#3439396)

Comment: @JasonC Too late, I already posted that as an answer.

Comment: GL takes indoor questions, granted they are gardening (plant) related.

Answer (score 5):

In all seriousness, [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) might be a good choice for you - they're all about finding ways to use things in the life to get the most optimally advantageous position.

In other words, they really are about manipulating real-world bugs.

Comment: So, it has come to this.

Comment: @JasonC https://xkcd.com/1022/ Required.

Comment: @JasonC If it makes you feel better though, this is what I usually think of 'lifehacks' https://xkcd.com/1494/